# Can a javascript code continue running throughout different web pages?

Tags: javascript, browser-automation

I am trying to code a javascript that runs throughout different web pages. The script should type something into a search bar, click search, click a result, then save each result text into an array. It looks something like:

```html
function returnresults(queries){
  arrayofcontent = [];

  for each query {
    type query in searchbar;
    submit search;
    result[0].click(); // go to first result
    arrayofcontent.push(pagecontent.innertext);
  }
  
  return arrayofcontent;
}
```

The issue is that the script seems to be stopping after the script clicks search, which makes me think that the script is unloading itself when moving to another page, even though I'm typing the script directly into the javascript console in Google Chrome. Does anyone know how to tell Google Chrome to keep running the script even after moving between pages?

Comment: This is not possible. But you can achieve this thing by using local storage of browser and save your data into local storage and on other page get it from local storage.

Comment: Since you tagged this [browser-automation]: use any of the available scriptable automation tools, which direct the browser *from outside* instead of running inside the web page (which scripts do even if entered in the browser console).

Comment: Thank you salmon, berg, scott, and manas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: No.

When you examine what's happening in a browser tab (including working with the console), you are only able to inspect what's loaded in that tab. If you navigate to another page in that tab, everything that was in memory from the last page is thrown out and the new page content is loaded.

What you need is to store the state of the script and then retrieve that state on the other page. Storing state can be done in many different ways ([cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), server-side databases) and you'll  need to decide which is right for your architecture and use case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to inject your script to different web pages you can do that by developing a chrome extension . A extension enables to inject your script depending on your logic

here is the link to get started

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted